# Что выбирается быстрее из бд Postgresql: числа или строки?

Tags: postgresql

Вопрос думаю туповат, но в матчасти не нашел ответа.
К примеру есть таблица
id(ключ) | наименование (строка) | country (?) | city (?)

Вот тут есть вопрос. Мне надо выбирать по нескольким параметрам, к примеру иногда по страна и город, иногда что-то одно. Что лучше использовать в колонках страна и город - числовые данные (индексы из других таблиц) или строковые названия этих стран и городов? 
100% у меня будут еще 2-е таблицы с городами и странами:

id (ключ) | страна (строка)

id (ключ) | город (строка)

Но запросов с JOIN точно не будет, т.к. данные по городам и странам будут на стороне клиента также.

Т.е. что выберется быстрее

[SQL]SELECT * FROM table WHERE country=421 AND city=547 [/SQL], если 
id(ключ) | наименование (строка) | country (число) | city (число) - и тут числа надо как-то индексом обозначить?

или

[SQL]SELECT * FROM table WHERE country="Германия" AND city="Берлин" [/SQL], если
id(ключ) | наименование (строка) | country (строка) | city (строка)

Comment: Быстрее выберется по тому полю, по которому будет построен индекс. от типа данных зависит слабо. но обеспечивать ссылочную целостность принято по id, так как в наименованиях могут быть ошибки. представьте, что у вас ошиблись в одной букве в городе и потом это расползлось в тысячи записей в зависимую таблицу и теперь нам надо исправить название ... да и места названия обычно больше занимают, а больше объем - дольше поднимать с диска

Answer (score 2):

Числа всегда будут работать быстрее. 
Индекс по ним будет весить меньше, обновятся и строится быстрее. 
Используй индекс btree на поля по которым будешь искать (country, city).